# Drupal - Print content in node template if tagged with certain taxonomy term?

Tags: drupal-theming

I want some content to only be printed in my node-type.tpl.php if the node has a certain taxonomy term.

With the following I can print the term's name if its ID is 5:

```
<?php print $node->taxonomy[5]->name ?>
```

Can I modify the code so it only prints something if the term ID is 5? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<?php if ($node->taxonomy == '5'): ?> 
    Print something here if the term ID is 5.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Im a bit of a newbie with advanced theming so I was hoping to not have to mess about with my template.php.

It seems more complicated than necessary but could the code from here be altered:
[Drupal - display blocks according to node's taxonomy term ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193745/drupal-display-blocks-according-to-nodes-taxonomy-term-id)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working:

```
<?php if ($node->taxonomy[5]): ?> 
    print stuff here
<?php endif; ?>
```